# Is there a secure DNS provider?

Tags: tls, dns

Is there a secure DNS provider? Kind of alternative to DNSCrypt.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.opendns.com/ ?

Comment: @OP: Please define "secure". As in: a provider that is less vulnerable to giving poisoned results, one that supports encrypted DNS, or something else?

Comment: Also, IIRC Stackexchange policy doesn't allow product recommendations.

Comment: @Nasrus, secure like in TLS. That I'm sure that the reply is not spoofed (resistant to man in middle attack). A month ago Turkish government started to redirect DNS providers like 8.8.8.8 to their own DNS providers. http://www.cso.com.au/article/541667/turkey_isps_hijack_google_dns_service_killing_bypass_twitter_youtube_ban/

Comment: @mcgyver5: Dnscrypt is (afaik only) provided by Opendns, so opendns is not an alternative. The question remains how secure in what respect?!

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of "secure":

- If you want nobody near you sniff at your DNS traffic, then you can use a VPN to a trusted endpoint and then use the DNS server there.
- If you want to serve your own DNS records in a safe way you can setup DNSSec, but beware that not all clients understand this (they usually fall back to insecure, but some might just fail).
- If you want to be sure that you don't get spoofed DNS replies, you should setup your host to only do DNSSec queries and only accept DNSSec replies. Unfortunately a large part of the internet does not protect their domains with DNSSec yet, so you need to either accept insecure (and possible spoofed) replies or restrict yourself to the "safer" part of the internet.
- It helps also to use only SSL (https) so that the host name in the certificate gets compared against the name in the URL and you get failures if somebody spoofed the DNS response. Of course this depends on the more or less broken PKI architecture of the internet (e.g. every CA can sign a certificate, no working revocation...).
- Or do you want a DNS server which screens the replies so you get rudimentary malware protection. One example of this service is opendns.